# $||f||_a = \left(\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}|f(x)|^2 \right)^{1/2} = 0$ implies $f = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis

The question is the following

> Let $X = C_b ([0,\infty))$ be the space of all bounded and continuous functions on $[0,\infty)$. For any $a > 0$, define
>   $$
>  ||f||_a = \left(\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}|f(x)|^2 \right)^{1/2}, \quad \forall f \in X
> $$
>
> 1. Show that $||\cdot||$ is a norm on $X$.
> 2. For any $a>b>0$, show that $||\cdot||_a$ and $||\cdot||_b$ are not equivalent on $X$.

For the first question, I left with the strictly positive property, namely
$$
||f||_a = 0 \quad \text{implies that }\quad f = 0
$$
I tried to use the mean value theorem, but it seems that it only works for closed interval. Any hint?

Also, for the second question, I don't know how to approach. The definition of equivalent norms seems too tedious here. Are there any other methods available?

Comment: Hint: if $f$ is not everywhere zero, then it must be nonzero on some interval $[A,B]$, which gives $e^{ax}|f(x)|^2>0$ on $[A,B]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is equivalent to having a continuous non-negative interval $(a,b); a<b$: if $f(x)>0$ for some $x \in (a,b)$ then, by continuity, $f>$0 is a 'hood $ N_h:=(x-h,x+h)$ of x. Consider a compact subset $ K:=K_{N_h}:=[x-h',x+h'] \subset N_h$ . Then f takes a minimum $m$ on $K$ so that $ \int_a^b f \geq m(b-a)>0$. In your case, both $e^{-ax}, |f(x)|^2$ are non-negative, and thus is their product, so the result applies. On the norm, since $m<f(x)<M$ by assumption, we have : $$ m/a  \leq \int_0^{ \infty}  m \int_0^{\infty} e^{-ax}|f(x)|^2 \leq M \int_0^{ \infty}e^{-ax} |f(x)|^2\leq M/a $$ and $$ m/b \leq  \int_0^{ \infty}  m \int_0^{\infty} e^{-bx}|f(x)|^2 \leq M \int_0^{ \infty}e^{-bx} |f(x)|^2 \leq M/b$$ so norms are not equivalent in that they are not reciprocal multiples of each other.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, but I was asking for a hint. Maybe consider to give a partial answer next time for another response.

Comment: @UnbelieveTable: Sorry, will do.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, if there is $x_0$ such that $f(x_0) > 0.$ Then, by continuity, there exists an interval $I$ such that $f(x) > \epsilon > 0, \ x \in I.$ Then you get easily a contradiction.

For your second question, take $f(x) = e^{b/2x}$. Then $\|f\|_b =  \infty$. And $\|f\|_a <  \infty.$